# Need nelp adding a count to an already complex SQL Function Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 function as shown:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Querytest2]
    (@UnitId INT, @UserId INT, @PublishedPageTypeId INT, @dir Char(4))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        CASE             
            WHEN @dir = 'ASC' THEN [Date]
        END 
        ASC, 
        CASE 
            WHEN @dir = 'DESC' THEN [Date]
        END
        DESC 
         ) AS row
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    PublishedPage
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitParent ON PublishedPage.UnitId = UnitParent.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy ON UnitParent.UnitId = UnitHierarchy.ParentId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitChild ON UnitHierarchy.ChildId = UnitChild.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitType ON UnitType.UnitTypeId = UnitParent.UnitTypeId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitRoleUser ON UnitChild.UnitId = UnitRoleUser.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (PublishedPage.UnitId = @UnitId) AND 
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND 
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND 
                        (UnitType.UnitTypeId = 2) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(4)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 

                    )
                UNION

                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    PublishedPage
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitParent ON PublishedPage.UnitId = UnitParent.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy ON UnitParent.UnitId = UnitHierarchy.ParentId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitChild ON UnitHierarchy.ChildId = UnitChild.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitType ON UnitType.UnitTypeId = UnitParent.UnitTypeId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitRoleUser ON UnitChild.UnitId = UnitRoleUser.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (PublishedPage.UnitId = @UnitId) AND 
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND 
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND 
                        (UnitType.UnitTypeId = 2) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(1)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )
                UNION

                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    PublishedPage
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitChild ON PublishedPage.UnitId = UnitChild.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH1 ON UnitChild.UnitId = UH1.ChildId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitParent ON PublishedPage.UnitId = UnitParent.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH2 ON UnitChild.UnitId = UH2.ChildId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit AS UnitChildren ON UH2.ChildId = UnitChild.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitType ON UnitType.UnitTypeId = UnitChildren.UnitTypeId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (PublishedPage.UnitId = @UnitId) AND 
                        (UnitType.UnitTypeId = 3) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(5)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )
                UNION
                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    PublishedPage
                INNER JOIN
                    Unit ON PublishedPage.UnitId = Unit.UnitId
                INNER JOIN
                    UnitType ON Unit.UnitTypeId = UnitType.UnitTypeId
                INNER JOIN
                    UnitRoleUser ON Unit.UnitId = UnitRoleUser.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (Unit.UnitId = @UnitId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND
                        (UnitType.UnitTypeId = 3) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(3)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )

                UNION
                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    UnitRoleUser
                INNER JOIN
                    Unit AS UnitParent ON UnitRoleUser.UnitId = UnitParent.UnitId
                INNER JOIN
                    Unit AS UnitChild ON UnitParent.VenueId = UnitChild.VenueId
                INNER JOIN
                    PublishedPage ON UnitChild.UnitId = PublishedPage.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (UnitParent.UnitId = @UnitId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND
                        (UnitParent.UnitTypeId = 3) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(2)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )
                UNION
                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    UnitRoleUser
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH1 ON UnitRoleUser.UnitId = UH1.ChildId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH2 ON UH1.ParentId = UH2.ParentId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit ON UH2.ChildId = Unit.UnitId
                INNER JOIN
                    PublishedPage ON Unit.UnitId = PublishedPage.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (UnitRoleUser.UnitId = @UnitId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND
                        (Unit.UnitTypeId = 3) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(7)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )
                UNION
                SELECT
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageId,
                    PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId,
                    PublishedPage.UnitId,
                    PublishedPage.UserId,
                    PublishedPage.VenueId,
                    PublishedPage.ImageReference,
                    ISNULL (PublishedPage.DateFrom,PublishedPage.CreatedOn) AS [Date],
                    PublishedPage.DateFrom,
                    PublishedPage.DateTo,
                    PublishedPage.TimeStart,
                    PublishedPage.VenueOther,
                    PublishedPage.LinkURL,
                    PublishedPageDistribution.Status,
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    UserPublishedPageHistoryId 
                                FROM
                                    UserPublishedPageHistory 
                                WHERE 
                                    (
                                        (UserId = @UserId) AND
                                        (UserPublishedPageHistory.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId)
                                    )
                            )
                            THEN 1 --'User Read'
                            ELSE 0 --'User Unread'
                            END
                    ) AS ItemRead,
                    PublishedPage.CreatedOn,
                    PublishedPage.ModifiedOn
                FROM
                    UnitRoleUser
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH1 ON UnitRoleUser.UnitId = UH1.ChildId
                INNER JOIN 
                    UnitHierarchy as UH2 ON UH1.ParentId = UH2.ParentId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Unit ON UH2.ChildId = Unit.UnitId
                INNER JOIN
                    PublishedPage ON Unit.UnitId = PublishedPage.UnitId
                INNER JOIN 
                    PublishedPageDistribution ON PublishedPageDistribution.PublishedPageId = PublishedPage.PublishedPageId
                INNER JOIN 
                    Distribution ON Distribution.DistributionId = PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId
                WHERE
                    (
                        (UnitRoleUser.UnitId = @UnitId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.UserId = @UserId) AND
                        (UnitRoleUser.Active = 1) AND
                        (Unit.UnitTypeId = 2) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.DistributionId IN(6)) AND
                        (PublishedPageDistribution.Status = 1) AND
                        (PublishedPage.PublishedPageTypeId = @PublishedPageTypeId) AND
                        (PublishedPage.Active = 1) 
                    )
                ) a
            ) b
        WHERE 
            (
                (
                    (@PublishedPageTypeId = 1) AND
                    (b.Date >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()))
                ) OR
                (
                    (@PublishedPageTypeId = 2) AND
                    (b.Date >= DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE()))
                )
            ) 
)
```

The function basically trawls the database for web content according to user criteria. The Function works just fine.

A sample of output is shown here [Results.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7IeK.jpg)

My question is this: As you can see from the results I am able to see whether a user has read an item or not in the `ItemRead` column.

How can I modify this SQL function to allow me to output an additional column showing the total number of read records so that I can return everything I need in one function call.

Kind regards

Comment: I don't understand the desired result.  Since ItemRead can only be 1 or 0, wouldn't the count also always be 1 or 0?   Wouldn't it be exactly the same as ItemRead?  Exactly what do you want to count?

Comment: I am looking for a total number of items read for all the rows returned. In the results I posted this would be = 2 as only two items have been read.

Comment: So every row in the resultset would have 2 for the ItemCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can add:

```
SUM(ItemRead) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId) CountRead
```

**edit**

Based on your comment that you want a total over all, regardless to user:

```
SUM(ItemRead) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) CountRead
```

Comment: HoneyBadger - you are a genius! That solution worked a treat and has saved me a lot of database I/O.

Thank you

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help. You can accept this answer for future users.

Comment: If you want the unread items counted you should replace `SUM(ItemRead)` with `SUM(CASE WHEN ItemRead = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`